# What steps can I take to troubleshoot why my server is not accessible over HTTPS after enabling SSL with Certbot?

Tags: nginx, ssl, web-server, aws-ec2

I'm looking for assistance in diagnosing and resolving this issue. What steps can I take to troubleshoot why my server is not accessible over HTTPS after enabling SSL with Certbot? Are there any common pitfalls or configuration settings I might have missed?

Any help or guidance in resolving this SSL issue would be greatly appreciated.

i have used this command certbot command sudo certbot --nginx and the syntax is successful after the certbot command i cant able to access my server
it is working in http but not working in https

this is the file under sites-available .file name default

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        
        #listen 443;
        #listen [::]:443;
        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html/waste-management-dev/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php;

        server_name yourdomain.in;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                  try_files $uri =404;
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
             include fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_index index.php;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
             #include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourserver.in/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourserver.in/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}

server {
    if ($host = yourserver.in) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name myserver;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: You don't have a `listen 443;` and `listen [::]:443;` in your config.

Comment: For starters. If that's not enough, consider elaborating on what "not working in https" means; what specific behaviors/errors you *do* observe.

Comment: i do understand what he said am just recomfirming it

Comment: i have added the 443 in conf file still the same @doneal24 pasted updated nginx file

Comment: please fix your config, for each host run a individual file, you only enabled on `server_name yourdomain.in;` the 443 and by the way `https://unwaste.in` works for me fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just basically posted only minor information, based on that, the Configuration might work:

```
# Default server configuration
# which means its a catch all for these that are not configured, if you use only one site, for this server you dont need a specific host
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
      location ~ \.cgi$ {
                gzip off;
                include fastcgi.conf;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        }


        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

```
#### NEW FILE !!!!!!
#### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/unwaste.in 
##start file

server {
        server_name unwaste.in;
        listen 80;
        return 307 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
        
# enable http2 support - if module if avaible
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

# enable http1.1 support - if module if avaible
#        listen 443 ssl;
#        listen [::]:443 ssl;
 
        root /var/www/html/waste-management-dev/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php;

        server_name unwaste.in;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                  try_files $uri =404;
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
             include fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_index index.php;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
             #include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
               deny all;
        }


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/unwaste.in/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/unwaste.in/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

#EOF
```

Remind, that /etc/nginx/sites-enabled can use multiple file and therefor you should do that, and dont touch the nginx.conf
Most Debian Based systems like Ubuntu and co do have the same behavior.

if the File(s) will not be loaded, you have to take at the end of the nginx for:

```
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

And please first discuss instead of downvote, thanks ;)

Comment: thanks it worked @djdomi